# convert encoding format

Tags: perl, file, encode

After super-searching a method to convert the encoding file in perl,
I'm always asking myself what is the best way to do this.

My problem is very simple :
I have many files in differents encoding (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, windows-1252 ... ) and , I want to convert all this files in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Do you know the encoding of each file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Text::Iconv](http://search.cpan.org/~mpiotr/Text-Iconv-1.7/Iconv.pm) is very effective and very fast in converting from and to most encodings. It's also very simple to use

```
use Text::Iconv;
$converter = Text::Iconv->new("fromcode", "tocode");
$converted = $converter->convert("Text to convert");
```

A simple example

```
use Text::Iconv;
my $converter = Text::Iconv->new("utf8", "iso-8859-1");
my $iso_8859_1_string = $converter->convert($some_utf8_string);
```

If you dont know the encoding of the file you are trying to convert, you can use [Encode::Detect::Detector](http://search.cpan.org/~jgmyers/Encode-Detect-1.01/Detector.pm) to find the encoding automatically.

```
use Encode::Detect::Detector;
my $charset = detect($string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Encode, documentation available from http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html ?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: You put *Perl* as the tag, and this is not a Perl solution. However, it does explain how you can quickly convert files from one encoding format to another, and maybe even help you figure out what encodings your files are in.

---

The  [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) command can easily convert files from one encoding to another. Let's say a file is in `UTF-8` format, and you want to covert it to ISO-8859-1 format:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 $utf8_file > $latin1_file
```

You can find a listing of the various file encodings that `iconv` can convert from or to by using the `-l` parameter. `iconv` has a lot of *aliases* for the various formats too, so you're pretty sure to get it right no matter what you might type. For example, for ISO-8859-1, the various aliases listed are:

```
CP819 IBM819 ISO-8859-1 ISO-IR-100 ISO8859-1 ISO_8859-1 ISO_8859-1:1987 L1 LATIN1 CSISOLATIN1
```

Of course, this doesn't tell you what the original encoding of the file actually is. This is where the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) may be able to help you.

I have a UTF-8 encoded test file called `text_utf.txt`:

```
File encoding test:

â Õ ¼ ¥
```

Now, I'll make another copy of the file encoded as ISO-8859-1 format:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 text_utf.txt > text_latin1.txt
```

If I give both of these files to the `file` command, it will tell me their encoding:

```
$ file test_*.txt
test_latin1.txt: ISO-8859 text
test_utf8.txt:   UTF-8 Unicode text
```

Notice that the `file` command can output the type of encoding, and it might be enough to use with the `iconv` command.

A few caveats: Not all encoding conversions will work. This is especially true if a file is encoded in `utf-8` format which can represent millions of unique characters, and you attempt to convert it into a format like `ISO-8859-1` which can only represent at most 255 characters:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t mac test_utf8.txt  > test_macroman.text  # The ¼ isn't a MacRoman character
iconv: test_utf8.txt:3:4: cannot convert
```

Also, the `file` command only looks at the first few blocks of the file, so if the characters that *specify* the encoded file are buried deep within the file, the `file` command may not see them. And, it is also possible that the `file` command will confuse two different encodings. `file` can easily tell whether a file is in `utf-8` format or not, but it may be unable to tell if a file is in one 255 byte character encoding format or another.

---

> That's all nice and good, but I'm on a Windows system, you idiot.

I suspected as much since you want to convert files from the more universal, Linux/Mac friendly UTF-8 encoding to ISO-8859-1 which is similar to Windows Code Page 1252 -- the standard Windows file encoding for the United States.

Still, you may find the combination of the `file` and `iconv` commands to be a good way to figure out your file encodings, and to covert them from one encoding to another.

If you are on a Windows system, you can download [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) which will give you all of the standard GNU utilities found on Linux systems (including a complete BASH shell). I've found Cygwin useful whenever I am on a Windows system and need to do something that the standard Windows's BATCH scripting cannot easily do - such as converting a massive amounts of files from one format to another.